# GIMP scale image cubic interpolation code

Tags: c, image, scale, gimp

I would like to take a look at the implementation of image scaling in GIMP, in particular I'm interested in the cubic interpolation.

I downloaded GIMP's source code ([gimp-2.9.8.tar.bz2](https://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.9/gimp-2.9.8.tar.bz2)) and I narrowed down the research up to the `gimp_item_scale` function in `gimp-2.9.2/app/core/gimpitem.c` :

```
void
gimp_item_scale (GimpItem              *item,
                 gint                   new_width,
                 gint                   new_height,
                 gint                   new_offset_x,
                 gint                   new_offset_y,
                 GimpInterpolationType  interpolation,
                 GimpProgress          *progress)
{
  GimpItemClass *item_class;
  GimpImage     *image;

  g_return_if_fail (GIMP_IS_ITEM (item));
  g_return_if_fail (progress == NULL || GIMP_IS_PROGRESS (progress));

  if (new_width < 1 || new_height < 1)
    return;

  item_class = GIMP_ITEM_GET_CLASS (item);
  image = gimp_item_get_image (item);

  if (gimp_item_is_attached (item))
    gimp_image_undo_group_start (image, GIMP_UNDO_GROUP_ITEM_SCALE,
                                 item_class->scale_desc);

  g_object_freeze_notify (G_OBJECT (item));

  item_class->scale (item, new_width, new_height, new_offset_x, new_offset_y,
                     interpolation, progress);

  g_object_thaw_notify (G_OBJECT (item));

  if (gimp_item_is_attached (item))
    gimp_image_undo_group_end (image);
}
```

The next step would be follow the call to `item_class->scale` where hopefully the scale operation takes place, but `scale` is a "virtual" method of the struct `_GimpItemClass` (`gimp-2.9.2/app/core/gimpitem.h:75`).

Do you have any idea how may I resolve that call or where should I look for the actual scaling operation (with cubic interpolation)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "core" operations of Gimp are implemented in the GEGL library. The code you want to look at is likely here:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl/-/blob/master/gegl/buffer/gegl-sampler-cubic.c